# How to unmount elements in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display an array which contains 1M items, the performance of the render is slow:

```
class Scroll extends Component {
    render() {
        let display = this.props.names.map
        (
            (name) => (
                <div> {name}</div>
            )
        )

        return (
            <div id='container'>
                <div className="scroll">
                    {display}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Trying to solve the performance issue here and I was thinking unmounting components that are not visible to the user. What is the best way of approaching the performance issue? Not trying to import a module/lib for this but build it from 'scratch'.

Comment: If you decide to downvote at least leave some comments.

Comment: Loading 1Million records in the DOM will definitely affect the performance.Instead you can implement the approach discussed in this article  https://blog.jscrambler.com/optimizing-react-rendering-through-virtualization/.         Try to load all of this in the catch and load it in the DOM when u need it.....

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to go with a server side paginated data table approach. Showing 1M records to an user is ineffective since a human cannot process that amount of data anyways. Check [Fixed Data Table 2](https://github.com/schrodinger/fixed-data-table-2) or [React Table](https://react-table.js.org/#/story/readme)